# How to interpret an equation with both growth rates and logged variables?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, econometrics, interpretation, macroeconomics

How do you interpret $\beta_{1}$ in an equation like this:

$$\frac { \Delta P _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i ,j } } { P _ { t } ^ { i ,j } } = \mu _ { j } + \beta _ { 1} \ln \left( P _ { t } ^ { i ,j } \right) + \epsilon _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i ,j } \ ?$$

$i$ is neighbourhood, $j$ is city, $P_{t}$ is median house price, $\mu_j$ is city fixed effects, $t = 2001$ and $k=5$ so $\frac { \Delta P _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i ,j } } { P _ { t } ^ { i ,j } }$ is the growth in house price from 2001 - 2006.

My coefficient is -0.97. My apologies for the simple question I'm still quite new to econometrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rise of 1% in median house prices will, on average, lead to a $-0.97/100 = -0.0097$ increase (or a $0.0097$ decrease: $0.97$ percentage points) in the 5-year rate of growth in house prices.

Comment: This formulation assumes a causal effect. If this is not assumed, you may say that all else being equal, if $\ln(P)$ and $\ln(P')$ differ by 1, the dependent variable is expected to differ by $\beta_1$ on average.